# Access Report: How to group on one field, but sort by another?

Tags: sorting, ms-access, report, grouping

I've read through similar questions and they don't seem to quite fit my issue or they're in a different environment.

I'm working in MS-Access 2016.

I have a customer complaints report which has fields: year, month, count([complaint #]), complaint_desc.
(complaint # is the literal ID number we assign to each complaint entered into the table)

I grouped the report by year and month and then grouped by complaint_desc and for each desc did a count of complaint number, and then did a count of complaint # to add up total complaints for the month and stuck it in the month footer which gives a result of something like this:

```
2020  03 <= (this is the month group header)

complaint desc | count of complaints/desc    
---------------------------------------------    
electrical     | 2                               {This section is 
cosmetic       | 6                               {in the Complaint_desc
mechanical     | 1                               {group footer
---------------------------------------------
                 9 <= (this is month group footer)
```

repeating the group for each month

This is all good. What I want to do is to sort the records within the complaint desc group in descending order of count(complaint#) so that it looks like:

```
2020  03 

complaint desc | count of complaints/category    
---------------------------------------------    
cosmetic       | 6
electrical     | 2                             
mechanical     | 1
---------------------------------------------                              
                 9
```

However nothing I do seems to work, the desc group's built-in sort "a on top" overrides sorting in the query. adding a sort by complaint# is ignored also. I tried to add a sort by count(complaint#) and access told me I can't have an aggregate function in an order by (but I think it would have been overridden anyway). I also tried to group by count(complaint#) also shot down as aggregate in a group by. Tried moving complaint_desc and count(complaint#) to the complaint# group header and it screwed up the total count in the month footer and also split up the complaint desc's defeating it's original purpose...

I really didn't think this change was going to be a big deal, but a solution has evaded me for a while now. I've read similar questions and tried to follow examples but they didn't lead to my intended result.

Any Idea?

Comment: Wouldn't using a sub query help?

Comment: @UnhandledException In what way? If I make a subquery and use it to sort, I believe the Complaint_Desc Group's built in "A on Top" sort will override it. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Thank you to @UnhandledException who got me thinking on the right track.

So here's what I did:
The original query the report was based on contained the following:

```
Design mode:

Field | Year      | Month     | Complaint_Desc | Complaint# |
Total | Group By  | Group By  | Group By       | Group By   |
Sort  |           |           |                |            |

or in SQL: 

SELECT Year, Month, [tbl Failure Mode].[Code description], [Complaint Data Table].[Complaint #] 
FROM [tbl Failure Mode] RIGHT JOIN [Complaint Data Table] ON [tbl Failure Mode].[ID code] = [Complaint Data Table].[Failure Mode]
GROUP BY Year, Month, [tbl Failure Mode].[Code description], [Complaint Data Table].[Complaint #];
```

And then I was using the report's group and sort functions to make it show how I wanted except for the hiccup I mentioned.

I made another query based upon that query:

```
Design mode:

Field | Year       | Month      | Complaint_Desc | Complaint# |
Total | Group By   | Group By   | Group By       | Count      |
Sort  | Descending | Descending |                | Descending |

or in SQL: 

SELECT [qry FailureMode].Year, [qry FailureMode].Month, [qry FailureMode].[Complaint_description], Count([qry FailureMode].[Complaint #]) AS [CountOfComplaint #], [qry FailureMode].Complaint
FROM [qry FailureMode]
GROUP BY [qry FailureMode].Year, [qry FailureMode].Month, [qry FailureMode].[Code description], [qry FailureMode].Complaint
ORDER BY [qry FailureMode].Year DESC , [qry FailureMode].Month DESC , Count([qry FailureMode].[Complaint #]) DESC;
```

Then I changed the report structure:

I eliminated the Complaint_Desc group, moved complaint_desc and CountofComplaint# (which is now not a function but it's own calculated field from my new query) to the DETAIL section of the report. Then I deleted my 2nd count(complaint#) that was in the month footer as a total for each month and replaced it with the "AccessTotalsCountOfComplaint #" which is =Sum([CountOfComplaint #]) which I had access auto-create by right-clicking on the CountofComplaint_Desc in details scrolling to "Total" and clicking on "Sum". (I deleted the extra AccessTotalsCountOfComplaint#'s that were outside of the Month Group Footer that I needed it for...)

Et Voila

I hope this helps someone else, and thank you again to Unhandled Exception who pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: That was nearly what I meant. As I understand you, you use two separate Microsoft Access query objects. I would have thought to use both in one query, so with a sub-query. I mean that's also possible. But in the end the result is the same. Glad that you got it working.

Comment: I see what you're saying. You are correct I have 2 query objects now. Full disclosure: I don't have a lot of experience with sub-queries; so it isn't where my mind goes right away. When you pointed out the method, I thought about it for a little, and it occurred to me, "OH... if I make another query based on this one... I'll have what I need. I need to study up so I can do things more efficiently like you suggested. Thanks again!